# Mousewheel event detection not currently working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

For some reason I'm having trouble trying to recognize the mousewheel event in Firefox. This is working in IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera but not FF. I am attaching an event listener on DOMMouseScroll, which should be recognized in FF.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YU4JM/)

```
$(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var evt = event || e || window.event;
    var delta = evt.detail < 0 || evt.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    if (delta < 0) {
        // scroll down
    } else {
        // scroll up
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code generates an error in the console. The line:

```
var evt = event || e || window.event;
```

is incorrect; there's no "event" variable in scope. You can just use "e" directly. The jQuery code will make sure your handler gets the event parameter as a parameter. Or:

```
$(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(evt) {
    var delta = evt.detail < 0 || evt.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    if (delta < 0) {
        // scroll down
    } else {
        // scroll up
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why the scroll up doesn't work with this solution?

Comment: Not off the top of my head; I'll check the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks.. yeah it's super weird it's just making everything down.

Comment: It's because the "detail" property is not available on the jQuery event object wrapper - you have to look at `evt.originalEvent.detail` to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/yDdXs/

Comment: Oh weird. Alright thanks so much you've been extremely helpful.

Comment: @RicardoArruda I'm not sure how IE handles mousewheel events; this question was specifically about Firefox.

Comment: @Pointy is the same problem that appears in the Chrome, only get the "down" event, funny that testing OP code, works on Chrome.

Comment: jQuery 1.9.1 :
 `var delta = event.originalEvent.detail < 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;`

Answer (score 3):

This code save my life.. Works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Internet Explorer, Opera...

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
if(event.deltaY < 0){
// wheeled up
}
else {
// wheeled down
}
});
```